# My customer object is null for some reason.

Tags: java, foreach, abstract-class

I have a foreach loop that iterates through each preferred customer and sums up their balances to create their total assets. However each time it looks at the customer object, it evaluates it to null. PreferredCustomer is a sub class of the abstract class Customer. I am assuming I am not doing the foreach loop correctly, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
 public static void getBalance() {
    for(Customer customer: preferredCustomers){
        ArrayList<Account> al = customer.getAccountList();
        for(Account account: al){
            totalAssets+=account.getBalance();
            //balance = account.getbalance();
        }
        customer.setBalance(totalAssets);
    }
}
```

Also, the Arraylist AccountList is an list of account objects for each customer.

Comment: Your loop is correct, it is most likely that preferredCustomers contains null values.

Comment: You will have to show the code snippet where you create/fill the `ArrayList`.

Comment: Your getBalance function does not get balances.

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, if you code is throwing a NPE you should include the exception in your post with a pointer to what line corresponds to your sample code:

- If you are throwing a NPE on the `for(Customer` loop, then your `preferredCustomers` field is `null`.
- If it throws a NPE on the `customer.getAccountList()` line then one of the elements in your `preferredCustomers` collection is `null`.
- If it throws a NPE on the `for(Account account` loop then one of your `preferredCustomers` has an account-list that is `null`.
- If it throws a NPE on the `totalAssets+=account.getBalance();` line then one of the accounts in the list is `null`.  It could also be that the balance field is a `null` `Long` object.

As @ColinD mentioned, learning [how to use a debugger in Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) is recommended.